# A Table Representing the altar

Tags: sources-mekorot, words, mizbeach-altar

I’ve heard of the concept that שולחנו של אדם דומה למזבח, *a person’s table resembles the altar.*

Does anyone know where this wording can be found?

Answer (score 4):

While this exact phraseology does not appear in [Chagigah 27a](https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah_27a.2), that seems to be the Gemara on which this is based:

> רבי יוחנן וריש לקיש דאמרי תרוייהו בזמן שבית המקדש קיים מזבח מכפר על אדם עכשיו שלחנו של אדם מכפר עליו
>
> R’ Yochanan and Reish Lakish both said: When the Beis HaMikdash stood, the Altar atoned for a person. Now, a person’s table atones for him.

Indeed, the [Beis Yosef (OC 180)](https://www.sefaria.org/Beit_Yosef,_Orach_Chaim.180.2.1) explicitly connects this Gemara to the custom to cover the knife when bentching:

> כתב הרוקח בסימן של"ב מכסין סכין בשעת בה"מ על שם לא תניף עליהם ברזל במכילתא אינו דין שיניף המקצר על המאריך ושלחן כמזבח בשילהי חגיגה כז. עכ"ל וכ"כ הרד"א וכ"כ בשבלי הלקט
>
> The Rokeach wrote in §332, “We cover the knife during bentching, based on ‘Do not wield an iron tool on them’ [Devarim 27:5, regarding the stones of the Altar]. In the Mechilta: ‘It’s not right to wield that which shortens [one’s life] on that which lengthens [it], and the table is like the Altar, at the end of Chagigah, 27a.” Likewise the Rada and Shibolei HaLeket wrote.

Comment: See also Zohar 1:191b

Answer (score 3):

[Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim, 167:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.167.5?vhe=Maginei_Eretz:_Shulchan_Aruch_Orach_Chaim,_Lemberg,_1893&lang=bi) which says:

> ומ"מ מצוה להביא על כל שלחן מלח קודם שיבצוע **כי השלחן דומה למזבח** והאכיל' לקרבן ונא' על כל קרבנך תקריב מלח (ב"י בשם שבולי הלקט) והוא מגין מן הפורענות (תו' והגהת אשיר"י פ' כיצד מברכין וע"ל ס"ס ק"ע):
>
> And never the less, it's a mitzvah to bring salt on every table prior to breaking (the bread) **because the table is similar to the altar**, etc.

Comment: Technically that’s the Rema. He also brings it down in OC 494:3 as well.

Comment: Please see link http://dafyomi.co.il/chagigah/points/cg-ps-027.htm