# When is a table considered as an altar?

Tags: halacha, eating, mizbeach-altar

This a sequel to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/105665/5275) for which an answer cites O.C. 167:5 that likens one's table to an altar.

My follow up questions:

- When? Only while eating? And is it only while eating a meal that contains bread, or any type of meal? What about a snack or if one drinks just water?
- Is it only for a dedicated eating table? What if the table is used for eating as well as working?

Comment: nice *hagdaros* 

Comment: What difference does it make that we could test if this status is present?

Comment: @DoubleAA E.G., do you need to remove the knife for saying *al hamichya*? And for 2nd question, if it's a multi-use table maybe even for *Birkat Hamazon* you can leave a knife there.

Comment: @DanF Beis Yosef brings two reasons that one has to remove the knife. If it’s because of שלחן דומה למזבח and that doesn’t applies to מזונות, then you perhaps have a נפק״מ between that and the מעשה שהיה (since the חורבן is discussed in על המחיה also).

Comment: It is NOT considered Halachicly, only allegorically, so I think it's up to the person.

Answer (score 2):

As [pointed out](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/105667/501) , the source is in [Chagiga 27a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Chagigah.27a.2?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en).

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Chagigah.27a.2?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Chagigah.27a.2.1&lang2=bi) and [Tosafos](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Chagigah.27a.2?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Chagigah.27a.2.1&lang2=bi) both say that the reason being that one does Hachnosas Orchim  at one's table.

Rashi:

> שולחנו מכפר עליו - בהכנסת אורחין:‏
>
> One's table atones - by inviting guests

Tosafos:

> שלחנו של אדם מכפר. דגדול כח הלגימא כדאיתא בהגדת חלק (סנהדרין דף קג.):‏
>
> One's table atones. Because the power of Legima is great, as we see in Sanhedrin 103b

<sup>Note that Tosafos in the printed version points to Sanhedrin 106a - a typo</sup>

If we go to [Sanhedrin 103b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sanhedrin.103b.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he) we learn:

> א"ר יוחנן משום רבי יוסי בן קסמא **גדולה לגימה** שהרחיקה שתי משפחות מישראל שנאמר (דברים כג, ה) על דבר אשר לא קדמו אתכם בלחם ובמים ‏
>
> Rabbi Yoḥanan says in the name of Rabbi Yosei ben Kisma: **Great is Legima**, as it distanced two clans from the Jewish people, as it is stated: “An Ammonite or a Moabite shall not enter into the assembly of the Lord…because they met you not with bread and with water” (Deuteronomy 23:4–5).

So we see that Legima is offering people food.

Putting it all together, I would propose that any location where one actually hosts guests has the *atonement value* of a Mizbeach. (This seems clear from Rashi; from reading Tosafos one could argue that even if it only has the potential to host guests but one hasn't yet done so, it would still qualify.)

I would also propose that any type of food being served would qualify, as the Ammonites and a Moabites were not expected to serve full meals; they were expected to be hospitable.

So to answer your #1: When? Once you've hosted guests at it, it has this special status.

And #2: Any surface - once it was used for hosting guests has this special status.

But I cannot find any concrete proof - just *reading between the lines*.